# HTML/CSS: Image Border

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, sass

I have the following code:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Merriweather|Open+Sans');
.square {
  max-width: 460px;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 20px #D9DBDF;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.square:hover {
  -webkit-transform: translate(20px, -10px);
  -ms-transform: translate(10px, -10px);
  transform: translate(10px, -10px);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
  box-shadow: 0 5px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
}

.square .square-image img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 220px;
  object-fit: cover;
  border-top-left-radius: 4px;
  border-top-right-radius: 4px;
  border: 5px solid #555;
}

.square .square-details {
  padding: 20px 30px 30px;
}

.h11 {
  margin: auto;
  text-align: left;
  font-family: 'Merriweather', serif;
  font-size: 24px;
}

p0 {
  text-align: justify;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #C8C8C8;
  line-height: 18px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  display: block;
}

.button56 {
  background-color: #0563bb;
  color: white;
  width: 100px;
  padding: 10px 18px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  font-size: 12px;
  margin-top: 18px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: 'merriweather';
}

.button56:hover {
  opacity: 0.9;
  color: white;
}

.square1:hover {
  -webkit-transform: translate(20px, -10px);
  -ms-transform: translate(10px, -10px);
  transform: translate(10px, -10px);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
  box-shadow: 0 5px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
}

.square1 .square-image1 img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 220px;
  object-fit: cover;
  border-top-left-radius: 4px;
  border-top-right-radius: 4px;
  border: 5px solid #555;
}

.square1 .square-details1 {
  padding: 20px 30px 30px;
}

.square1 {
  max-width: 460px;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 20px #D9DBDF;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .square1 {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-top: 54px;
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .square1 .square-image1 img {
    height: 230px !important;
    border: 5px solid #555;
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
  }
  .square .square-image img {
    height: 230px !important;
    border: 5px solid #555;
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
  }
  .square,
  .square1 {
    max-width: 460px;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .h11 {
    width: 100% !important;
  }
}

.containerE {
  --bs-gutter-x: 1.5rem;
  width: 100%;
  padding-right: calc(var(--bs-gutter-x) / 2);
  padding-left: calc(var(--bs-gutter-x) / 2);
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .containerE {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    padding: 20px;
    justify-content: center;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="section-title">
    <h2>Featured Blogs Of The Day</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="container" style="display: flex; justify-content: space-between;">
    <div class="containerE" style="display: flex; justify-content: space-between;">
      <div class="square">
        <div class="square-image">
          <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/396547/pexels-photo-396547.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500">
        </div>

        <div class="square-details">
          <h3 class="h11">“Chances Of My Uni/College Admission?”</h3>
          <p0>It is that time of the year again (yay!) where we — high school students — are supposed to fill out the applications and land in our dream Universities/Colleges!</p0>
          <div><a href="https://m-hussainomer03.medium.com/chances-of-my-uni-college-admission-20bc0efec0af" target="_" class="button56">Read More</a></div>
        </div>

      </div>
      <div class="square1">
        <div class="square-image1">
          <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/396547/pexels-photo-396547.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500">
        </div>

        <div class="square-details1">
          <h3 class="h11">My Career Advice To You: Take These Steps...</h3>
          <p0>Humans tend to make mistakes — and its completely normal as it results in the growth and development of an individual — either psychologically or physically.</p0>
          <div><a href="https://m-hussainomer03.medium.com/my-career-advice-to-you-take-these-steps-to-ultimate-prosperity-6c0687ce9c9f" target="_" class="button56">Read More</a></div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

When you run the above code, open it on a new page, and then **zoom out to 75%**, you can start to see white lines show up around the border of the image. I would like to remove that. How would I do that?

If you are still unsure of what white lines I am talking about, then refer to the following image:

[image]

The white lines are around the border of the image. How would I remove them? The white line also might be the space between the image and the border, but is there any way to remove it?

Any suggestions?

Comment: remove border on image

Comment: But I just want the white spacing to disappear, not the border

Comment: I think the best way to solve this is to change it from an img element inside a div, to using the img as the background of the div. That way you can use the `cover` css attribute to avoid any whitespace gaps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused by some strange border rendering by the browser.

To solve this, you can apply an inset box shadow such that it isn't noticeable yet it masks the spacing when zooming out:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Merriweather|Open+Sans');
.square {
  max-width: 460px;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 20px #D9DBDF;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.square:hover {
  -webkit-transform: translate(20px, -10px);
  -ms-transform: translate(10px, -10px);
  transform: translate(10px, -10px);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
  box-shadow: 0 5px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
}

.square .square-image img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 220px;
  object-fit: cover;
  border-top-left-radius: 4px;
  border-top-right-radius: 4px;
  border: 5px solid #555;
}

.square .square-details {
  padding: 20px 30px 30px;
}

.h11 {
  margin: auto;
  text-align: left;
  font-family: 'Merriweather', serif;
  font-size: 24px;
}

p0 {
  text-align: justify;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #C8C8C8;
  line-height: 18px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  display: block;
}

.button56 {
  background-color: #0563bb;
  color: white;
  width: 100px;
  padding: 10px 18px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  font-size: 12px;
  margin-top: 18px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: 'merriweather';
}

.button56:hover {
  opacity: 0.9;
  color: white;
}

.square1:hover {
  -webkit-transform: translate(20px, -10px);
  -ms-transform: translate(10px, -10px);
  transform: translate(10px, -10px);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
  box-shadow: 0 5px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
}

.square1 .square-image1 img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 220px;
  object-fit: cover;
  border-top-left-radius: 4px;
  border-top-right-radius: 4px;
  border: 5px solid #555;
}

.square1 .square-details1 {
  padding: 20px 30px 30px;
}

.square1 {
  max-width: 460px;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 20px #D9DBDF;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .square1 {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-top: 54px;
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .square1 .square-image1 img {
    height: 230px !important;
    border: 5px solid #555;
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
  }
  .square .square-image img {
    height: 230px !important;
    border: 5px solid #555;
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
  }
  .square,
  .square1 {
    max-width: 460px;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .h11 {
    width: 100% !important;
  }
}

.containerE {
  --bs-gutter-x: 1.5rem;
  width: 100%;
  padding-right: calc(var(--bs-gutter-x) / 2);
  padding-left: calc(var(--bs-gutter-x) / 2);
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .containerE {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    padding: 20px;
    justify-content: center;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
}

img{
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px black;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="section-title">
    <h2>Featured Blogs Of The Day</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="container" style="display: flex; justify-content: space-between;">
    <div class="containerE" style="display: flex; justify-content: space-between;">
      <div class="square">
        <div class="square-image">
          <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/396547/pexels-photo-396547.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500">
        </div>

        <div class="square-details">
          <h3 class="h11">“Chances Of My Uni/College Admission?”</h3>
          <p0>It is that time of the year again (yay!) where we — high school students — are supposed to fill out the applications and land in our dream Universities/Colleges!</p0>
          <div><a href="https://m-hussainomer03.medium.com/chances-of-my-uni-college-admission-20bc0efec0af" target="_" class="button56">Read More</a></div>
        </div>

      </div>
      <div class="square1">
        <div class="square-image1">
          <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/396547/pexels-photo-396547.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500">
        </div>

        <div class="square-details1">
          <h3 class="h11">My Career Advice To You: Take These Steps...</h3>
          <p0>Humans tend to make mistakes — and its completely normal as it results in the growth and development of an individual — either psychologically or physically.</p0>
          <div><a href="https://m-hussainomer03.medium.com/my-career-advice-to-you-take-these-steps-to-ultimate-prosperity-6c0687ce9c9f" target="_" class="button56">Read More</a></div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

#### Comparison

| With inset box-shadow | Without inset box-shadow |
| --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] |

<sup>(click to enlarge)</sup>

Comment: a little overflow on chrome

Comment: @Spectric, hey could you state what you changed/added/removed in my code? I can know exactly what you added that way and use it in the future! Thanks!

Comment: @CodeUser2300 I added `img{ box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px black; }`

Comment: @Spectric, just a question, why did you add 10px in the box-shadow? Instead of 10px, can I use 20px?

Comment: @CodeUser2300 At 10 pixels the inset shadow usually covers up the white spacing. Beyond that increasing the box shadow will only affect the image.